# Missing abstract methods error in database testing with DbUnit extension in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, dbunit

I have following error after running some basic database test in Zend Framework with phpUnit

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Metadata_Generic contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IMetaData::disablePrimaryKeys, PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IMetaData::enablePrimaryKeys) in D:\www\~library\zend_latest\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Db\Metadata\Generic.php on line 167
```

My test is very similar to one from ZF documentation:

```
class BugsTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase
{
private $_connectionMock;

/**
 * Returns the test database connection.
 *
 * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
 */
protected function getConnection()
{
    if($this->_connectionMock == null) {
        $connection = Zend_Db::factory(...);
        $this->_connectionMock = $this->createZendDbConnection(
            $connection, 'zfunittests'
        );
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($connection);
    }
    return $this->_connectionMock;
}

/**
 * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet
 */
protected function getDataSet()
{
    return $this->createFlatXmlDataSet(
        dirname(__FILE__) . '/_files/bugsSeed.xml'
    );
}
}
```

My "fix" for the problem was to not to impelemt `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IMetaData` in `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Metadata_Generic` library. Now everything runs ok but I wonder if there is any proper way to resolve this problem.

I'm using ZF 11.11, phpUnit 3.6.10 and DbUnit 1.1.2.

Comment: For those that will come across this problem I found two more sollutions in ZF Issue Tracker [http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11781](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11781), first is to add missing methods in Generic.php lib (obvious), second one is to downgrade to phpUnit 3.5.15

Answer (score 2):

Zend 1.11 doesn't support PHPUnit 3.6, you need to downgrade do PHPUnit 3.5 or 3.4.

Try to uninstall and re-install PHPUnit and his dependencies in the specific order as shown in http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

Also, see http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11781

Comment: Thanks; I wish I found this sooner.  And I wish there were Composer packages for 3.5.15 at https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit

Comment: Also, beware PHPUnit PEAR channel is going to be retired in a few months (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method). At this point you will probably need to manually include PHPUnit, putting it in your library path for instance

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier alternative method to downgrading PHPUnit to 3.4 or 3.5 without uninstalling the latest version (mentioned in http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11828).

The alternative is to run multiple versions of PHPUnit. For example, to install PHPUnit/3.5 into the `/opt` directory:

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
sudo pear install --installroot /opt/phpunit35 pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.5.15
sudo ln -s /opt/phpunit35/usr/bin/phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit35
```

After installation, manually edit `/opt/phpunit35/usr/bin/phpunit` to set up the include paths correctly. Add the following to the top of the file:

```
// Ubuntu / Debian
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/../share/php',
    get_include_path()
)));

// CentOS
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/../share/pear',
    get_include_path()
)));
```

PHPUnit/3.5 is now available from the command line by executing `phpunit35`.

Note that the officially supported version for ZF/1.11 is PHPUnit/3.4; however, I prefer to use 3.5 since it has some extra features that do not seem to break compatibility.

Finally, update any build scripts (such as Jenkins, Makefiles or IDE projects) to point to `phpunit35` instead of `phpunit` when running test suites.

See also: http://tech.vg.no/2011/11/29/running-multiple-versions-of-phpunit/